# React Semantic UI Sidebar Issue

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to implement a interactive sidebar from react semantic UI, I copied the code as is from their website, but I'm not too sure how to implement it:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Sidebar, Segment, Button, Menu, Image, Icon, Header } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class SidebarLeftScaleDown extends Component {

  state = { visible: false }

  toggleVisibility = () => this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible })

  render() {
    const { visible } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.toggleVisibility}>Toggle Visibility</Button>
        <Sidebar.Pushable as={Segment}>
          <Sidebar as={Menu} animation='scale down' width='thin' visible={visible} icon='labeled' vertical inverted>
            <Menu.Item name='home'>
              <Icon name='home' />
              Home
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item name='gamepad'>
              <Icon name='gamepad' />
              Games
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item name='camera'>
              <Icon name='camera' />
              Channels
            </Menu.Item>
          </Sidebar>
          <Sidebar.Pusher>
            <Segment basic>
              <Header as='h3'>Application Content</Header>
              <Image src='/assets/images/wireframe/paragraph.png' />
            </Segment>
          </Sidebar.Pusher>
        </Sidebar.Pushable>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SidebarLeftScaleDown
```

I am then calling it from another class like this:

```
<SidebarLeftScaleDown/>
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
[INFO] Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/Users/611727594/Desktop/OverchargeSpringProject/src/main/js/sidebarLeftScaleDown.js: Unexpected token (6:12)
[INFO] 
[INFO]   4 | class SidebarLeftScaleDown extends Component {
[INFO]   5 | 
[INFO] > 6 |       state = { visible: false }
[INFO]     |             ^
[INFO]   7 | 
[INFO]   8 |       toggleVisibility = () => this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible })
[INFO]   9 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize state in the constructor

```
class SidebarLeftScaleDown extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {visible: false}
  }

  toggleVisibility() {
    this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible });
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: that solves the error but its not rendering properly, its just displaying as normal html

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Please accept the answer (if it helped answer the posted question) and post an new question for the new problem you are experiencing :)

Answer (score 0):

This is [class properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields) which is a [proposal in stage 2](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields).
You will need a babel plugin for it [babel-plugin-transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/).

Or you can do it in the normal ES6 syntax and initialize the state inside the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       visible: false
    }
  }
```